# Java Eclipse SWIXml Error

Tags: java, eclipse, swixml

I went to [SwiXml](http://swixml.org/) website and downloaded the **swixml_240.rar** and also downloaded the **swixml.jar** file in [Java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadswixmljar.htm) website just to be sure. In eclipse I configure the build path and add the swixml.jar downloaded in Java2s. Here is my source code:

```
package com.inventory.ui;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.swixml.SwingEngine;

public class TestCml 
{
    private int clicks;
    public JTextField tf;
    public JLabel cnt;

    public Action submit = new AbstractAction()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            tf.setText( tf.getText() + "#");
            cnt.setText( String.valueOf( ++clicks));
        }
    };

    private TestCml() throws Exception
    {
        new SwingEngine(this).render("C://Users/Colinn/JavaWorkspace/Patient Management System/src/com/inventory/ui/textcml.xml").setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        new TestCml();
    }
}
```

And the **textcml.xml** file: (Note: In eclipse there is an X sign on line 2 of this xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<frame xmlns="http://www.swixml.org/2007/SwixmlTags" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.swixml.org/2007/SwixmlTags http://www.swixml.org/2007/swixml.xsd" size="640,280" title="Hello SWIXML World" defaultCloseOperation="JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE">

<panel constraints="BorderLayout.CENTER">
<label labelfor="tf" font="Georgia-BOLD-12" foreground="blue" text="Hello World!"/>
<textfield id="tf" columns="20" Text="Swixml"/>
<button text="Click Here" action="submit"/>

</panel>
<panel constraints="BorderLayout.SOUTH">
<label font="Georgia-BOLD-36" text="Clicks:"/>
<label font="Georgia-BOLD-36" id="cnt"/>
</panel>
</frame>
```

And when I run the program this is the error. It always look for  **SwingEngine.class** even though it is in the JAR file.

[image]

[image]

And now I tried to change the Build path in eclipse. I removed the swixml.jar from the Java2s and extracted the RAR file from the SwiXml website. These are the
contents of the RAR. Which is different from the file provided from the Java2s.

Inside the **build** folder there is also a **swixml.jar** which I added in my build path in eclipse but also provided a **same error** when I run the program
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The attached jar only contains class files not the source code. You must go to their site and find out the sources.jar, if you want to see actual code content.

Below jar should give you the source file if you want to actually read the code.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/swixml/swixml/2.5.20110914/swixml-2.5.20110914-sources.jar
Click on attach source and point to above downloaded jar.

If you have sourcecode already, sometimes we have to import/ configure build path to point to actual source code in IDE.

Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Thanks but It produces another error.    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Resource could not be found C://Users/Colinn/JavaWorkspace/Patient Management System/src/com/inventory/ui/textcml.xml
 at org.swixml.SwingEngine.render(Unknown Source)
 at com.inventory.ui.TestCml.<init>(TestCml.java:29)
 at com.inventory.ui.TestCml.main(TestCml.java:34)

Comment: So If jar only contains class files why is some jars work properly even though I haven't added its source code like jdbc jar files ?

Comment: Depends on the way it is set up and configured. For Ex: If you are using maven, check in your local repository(c:/users/../.m2/com..   ) whether particular source.jar exists for that module. For some it exist and for other it does not.  Regarding the exception - Not sure what your requirements are here, but seems like it is looking for some xml file and when not found it throws IoException. To fix this either place xml file in the targeted path or project class path.